# Typescript Dynamic Property key from value of another key

Tags: typescript

I have email-address field in `id` of constant field `loginFields`

I want to add email-address as a property field to the interface `LoginFields`

I could resolve the error. Need Help to fix this error

[Type Script PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA5gSzAMWQUzgEwgXgG0AoGMmAb1PJrgEMAjbAFUwA8oAuAIgFEBbOsjgw6OHACdMECNwA01GmXpM4aEBJ6ZBwgLRjJ02QqXlkOLTrj7xUmfMVKwdfpktC4D02SgBPAA5u3NoeXt50AK5QIADCIPz%20cJhQQSHCYabIEABKmACOEchSFlASEZgm3ol0wJgAFiC4mJp8VqK2RtzkjgC%20lWRU3vCMLOxc3AAKdDIA7ho4GUoq2Oot-tMQcxIL-UrmPOuz84s0zq4HG1s7jjR%20gRdH2yfkkdFxCUkpPMARElJgUF0h02x12NCyuQKRUwJTKFRu5GqtQaTRaU0eC26NB6xAAusRiKgUhIAGY1TAwAAySFQGGweEojmWcFYHE4MGgElQiAA3EyRmoNOzOdy%20eCLBzSqLHGc3JKuWBeY47nKRYqxS8orF4olkqqperHBD8oViuyGCBGpg6GANWQkfVGjhmpw1UqccRPjASVhcBAAMpQOhfKk09C%20vCEXF80CQWA%20%20kEBAocOJvkJv0AOhJGl4NTqAAoMzh8AA%20YsBoMpQjFzPmXH4ADkjYAlDygA)

What I tried and did not work

```
const loginFields=[
    {
        labelText:"Email address",
        labelFor:"email-address",
        id:"email-address",
        name:"email",
        type:"email",
        autoComplete:"email",
        isRequired:true,
        placeholder:"Email address"   
    },
    {
        labelText:"Password",
        labelFor:"password",
        id:"password",
        name:"password",
        type:"password",
        autoComplete:"current-password",
        isRequired:true,
        placeholder:"Password"   
    }
]

type LoginFieldAll = {
    labelText: string;
    labelFor: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    autoComplete: string;
    isRequired: boolean;
    placeholder:string;
}

interface ValToKey {[key: string]: string};
let Fields:ValToKey = {};
loginFields.forEach((field) => {
    Fields[field.id] = 'string';
});
type FieldSchemaTypes = {[key: string]: string };
type Keys = typeof Fields;
type FieldSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof FieldSchemaTypes>> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]?: FieldSchemaTypes[T[K]]
}
```

```js
type CustomField = FieldSchema<Keys> &  LoginFieldAll 
let fieldsState: CustomField[];
const fields=loginFields;
fields.forEach(field=>fieldsState[field.id]= '');
```

I get error in `fieldsState[field.id]`